# Combining objects in array based on key values

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects with a common key. I would like to combine all the objects within the array based on key values.

My array:

```
let array = [
  {
    "day": "Monday",
    "item1": "abc"
  },
  {
    "day": "Tuesday",
    "item1": "def"
  },
  {
    "day": "Monday",
    "item2": "123"
  },
  {
    "day": "Tuesday",
    "item2": "456"
  }
]
```

Based on the example, I want to combine the objects within my array based on the common ***day*** key values and merge the rest of the other key value pairs (the rest of the keys are dynamic).

Expected output:

```
[
  {
    "day": "Monday",
    "item1": "abc",
    "item2": "123"
  },
  {
    "day": "Tuesday",
    "item1": "def",
    "item2": "456"
  }
]
```

I have tried using `Lodash` and plain `ES6` but still unable to come up with a solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lodash reduce function, like this:

```
let array = [
  {
    "day": "Monday",
    "item1": "abc"
  },
  {
    "day": "Tuesday",
    "item1": "def"
  },
  {
    "day": "Monday",
    "item2": "123"
  },
  {
    "day": "Tuesday",
    "item2": "456"
  }
]

let merged = _.reduce(array, function(result, value, key) {

  let item = result.find(item => item.day === value.day);

  if (!item) {
    result.push(value)
  } else {
     _.merge(item, value);
  }

  return result;
} , []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Array#reduce` , `Spread Operator` and approach with ES6

```js
const arr = [ { "day": "Monday", "item1": "abc" }, { "day": "Tuesday", "item1": "def" }, { "day": "Monday", "item2": "123" }, { "day": "Tuesday", "item2": "456" } ];

let res =  arr.reduce((acc,{day,...rem})=>( acc[day]  = acc[day] ? {...acc[day],...rem} : {day,...rem},acc),{});

console.log(Object.values(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

```
_(array).groupBy('day').map(_.spread(_.assign)).value()
```